# How to show all unread emails and save as a favourite folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I have many email accounts (all POP3) and I'd like to make a smart folder to display unread emails.

I have read how to use the New Search Folder to create a folder with only unread items and then I can move this to favourites. The problem is this is limited to each data file, and as such, I'd have many 'unread' folders in my favourites.

I've also read the other option is to perform a search but this search also can't be stored in favourites.

Is it possible to have a smart folder in Outlook 2016, where I can have 1 folder which shows all the unread emails of all my accounts

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't. There is no way in Outlook to create a Search Folder that will search items from multiple stores (data files/mailboxes/...).

Comment: Yes, I did have the feeling this was the case... I wonder if it could be done with an MS-AddIn. Thanks

Comment: You can't even with add-in.

Comment: that isn't correct. The AddIn can easily read all unread emails in all accounts and in a different Window display this information. It wouldn't be useful or easily interactable without a lot of work but, it showing this Window is possible

Comment: I mean, with the existing add-in =) You can write the addin by yourself, of course!

Comment: This is seriously annoying, and has been requested of every Outlook I've seen since 2010. I am not sure people at Microsoft use email from multiple accounts. As a client application, this is a serious oversight that even the open-source Thunderbird can do. The fact that there are ways in VBA code around it just proves Microsoft is really half-assing it these days. Their attention lies elsewhere, but they should be bolstering their Office products which are the best thing about MS.